# Create generic objects from a list of keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a function that will take a type `T` and a `Map` of keys/value that returns a new object of type `T` with its fields set to what was given in the `Map`.

I have written the following code

```js
function create<T extends object>(keys: Map<string, number>): T {
    const obj: T = Object.create({}) as T;
    keys.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (Reflect.has(obj, key)) {
            Reflect.set(obj, key, value);
        } else {
            throw new TypeError(`Type ${typeof(obj)} doesnt have a field ${key}`);
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

interface Foo {
    id: number;
}

const keys = new Map<string, number>();
keys.set("id", 10);

const f: Foo = create<Foo>(keys);
console.log(f.id);
```

But it throws an exception at runtime

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Type object doesnt have a field id
            throw new TypeError(`Type ${typeof(obj)} doesnt have a field ${key}`);
```

Upon inspection, `Reflect.ownKeys(obj)` returns nothing, why? Doesn't the compiler know that `obj` is of type `T`?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript annotations only help you at compile time.  They don't exist at runtime.  In this code you are using runtime errors `throw new TypeError` but you will not know at compile time whether that error will be thrown.

There are some fundamental "what are you trying to accomplish" questions that you need to ask yourself about this code.

What does the type `T` represent?  How do *you* know what `T` is, and how does typescript know?

With your current function, typescript cannot possibly infer the type of `T` because it doesn't depend on any of the variables of your code.  As far as typescript is concerned, there is no relationship between the key-value pairs of the `Map` variable `keys` and the return type `T`.

Your `const f: Foo = create<Foo>(keys);` will return the correct type `Foo` because you have told it to, but it won't give you any indication of whether or not your map `keys` is valid.  Because, again, there is no stated relationship between the `Map` and `T`.

At runtime, all that is known about `obj` is that it is `{}`.  Type annotations don't exist at runtime.  So `Reflect.has(obj, key)` will always be `false`.

Is there a reason that you are using `Map` at all, rather than using an `object` to store your defaults?

You need to entirely rethink this code.